# calling JMS APIs using mysql

Tags: mysql, jms, openjms

I have an application using MySQL 5.5 db in a windows machine and a JVM running on a linux machine. I want to send JMS messages to the JVM from mysql when a value is inserted in one of the tables. I have seen that we can configure openjms with mysql but, how  to we use it to call the JMS APIs ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Openjms requires a substrate for holding messages - this is where mysql comes into the picture - MySQL has no functionality to call java / create messages. Although it would in principe be possible to insert directly into the message queue using mysql this is a really bad idea.

You need to implement some code (most likely in Java) to capture the event and create a message.

Comment: Is the case only with Openjms ? What about using ActiveMQ with Mysql? Even then how do we insert a message into the queue ? Using a procedure or something ?